# What is the "M- notation" and where is it documented?

Tags: special-characters, cat, keycode, notation, non-printing-characters

The [man page of cat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat)  says:

```
-v, --show-nonprinting
    use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

What is the `M-` notation and where is it documented?

Example:

```
$cat log -A
wrote 262144 bytes from file test.x in 9.853947s (25.979 KiB/s)^M$
^M> ^H^H  ^H^H>
```

What do `^M` and `^H` mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was wondering this too. I checked the source but it seemed easier to create a input file to get the mapping.

I created a test input file with a Perl scrip `for( my $i=0 ; $i < 256; $i++ ) {  print ( sprintf( "%c is %d %x\n", $i, $i ,$i ) ); }` and then ran it through cat -v

Also if you see M-oM-;M-? at the start of a file it is the UTF-8 byte order mark.

**Scroll down through these to get to the M- values:**

```
^@ is 0 0
^A is 1 1
^B is 2 2
^C is 3 3
^D is 4 4
^E is 5 5
^F is 6 6
^G is 7 7
^H is 8 8
(9 is tab)
(10 is NL)
^K is 11 b
^L is 12 c
^M is 13 d
^N is 14 e
^O is 15 f
^P is 16 10
^Q is 17 11
^R is 18 12
^S is 19 13
^T is 20 14
^U is 21 15
^V is 22 16
^W is 23 17
^X is 24 18
^Y is 25 19
^Z is 26 1a
^[ is 27 1b
^\ is 28 1c
^] is 29 1d
^^ is 30 1e
^_ is 31 1f
...printing chars removed...
^? is 127 7f
M-^@ is 128 80
M-^A is 129 81
M-^B is 130 82
M-^C is 131 83
M-^D is 132 84
M-^E is 133 85
M-^F is 134 86
M-^G is 135 87
M-^H is 136 88
M-^I is 137 89
M-^J is 138 8a
M-^K is 139 8b
M-^L is 140 8c
M-^M is 141 8d
M-^N is 142 8e
M-^O is 143 8f
M-^P is 144 90
M-^Q is 145 91
M-^R is 146 92
M-^S is 147 93
M-^T is 148 94
M-^U is 149 95
M-^V is 150 96
M-^W is 151 97
M-^X is 152 98
M-^Y is 153 99
M-^Z is 154 9a
M-^[ is 155 9b
M-^\ is 156 9c
M-^] is 157 9d
M-^^ is 158 9e
M-^_ is 159 9f
M-  is 160 a0
M-! is 161 a1
M-" is 162 a2
M-# is 163 a3
M-$ is 164 a4
M-% is 165 a5
M-& is 166 a6
M-' is 167 a7
M-( is 168 a8
M-) is 169 a9
M-* is 170 aa
M-+ is 171 ab
M-, is 172 ac
M-- is 173 ad
M-. is 174 ae
M-/ is 175 af
M-0 is 176 b0
M-1 is 177 b1
M-2 is 178 b2
M-3 is 179 b3
M-4 is 180 b4
M-5 is 181 b5
M-6 is 182 b6
M-7 is 183 b7
M-8 is 184 b8
M-9 is 185 b9
M-: is 186 ba
M-; is 187 bb
M-< is 188 bc
M-= is 189 bd
M-> is 190 be
M-? is 191 bf
M-@ is 192 c0
M-A is 193 c1
M-B is 194 c2
M-C is 195 c3
M-D is 196 c4
M-E is 197 c5
M-F is 198 c6
M-G is 199 c7
M-H is 200 c8
M-I is 201 c9
M-J is 202 ca
M-K is 203 cb
M-L is 204 cc
M-M is 205 cd
M-N is 206 ce
M-O is 207 cf
M-P is 208 d0
M-Q is 209 d1
M-R is 210 d2
M-S is 211 d3
M-T is 212 d4
M-U is 213 d5
M-V is 214 d6
M-W is 215 d7
M-X is 216 d8
M-Y is 217 d9
M-Z is 218 da
M-[ is 219 db
M-\ is 220 dc
M-] is 221 dd
M-^ is 222 de
M-_ is 223 df
M-` is 224 e0
M-a is 225 e1
M-b is 226 e2
M-c is 227 e3
M-d is 228 e4
M-e is 229 e5
M-f is 230 e6
M-g is 231 e7
M-h is 232 e8
M-i is 233 e9
M-j is 234 ea
M-k is 235 eb
M-l is 236 ec
M-m is 237 ed
M-n is 238 ee
M-o is 239 ef
M-p is 240 f0
M-q is 241 f1
M-r is 242 f2
M-s is 243 f3
M-t is 244 f4
M-u is 245 f5
M-v is 246 f6
M-w is 247 f7
M-x is 248 f8
M-y is 249 f9
M-z is 250 fa
M-{ is 251 fb
M-| is 252 fc
M-} is 253 fd
M-~ is 254 fe
M-^? is 255 ff
```

Comment: If one pushes further (e.g. `for( my $i=0 ; $i < 512; $i++ ) ...`) the next 64 lines after `M-^?` give `M-DM-^@`, `M-DM-^A`, `M-DM-^B`..., then the next 64 lines give `M-EM-^@`, `M-EM-^A`, `M-EM-^B`... Any idea why it doesn't rather recycle completely and start at `M-^@M-^@`, `M-^@M-^A`, `M-^@M-^B`..., and then `M-^AM-^@`, `M-^AM-^A`, `M-^AM-^B`... ?

Comment: I might have found out why. $i is interpreted as the *code point* value of a Unicode character. If $i ≤ 255, the character is encoded in a 8-bit format. Beyond, the character is encoded in a UTF-8 format of two or more 8-bit values. In `cat`, the incoming string is read piece by piece and stored in an *unsigned char* variable 'ch' that can contain only 8 bits (0‑255). 'ch' is then processed to be converted into either a *printable* character or *nonprintable* characters under the ^ or M- notation in the (0–255) range. For characters with UTF-8 format in the string, multiple 'ch' reads occur.

Comment: Digging further, there might be something special happening in the Perl line (maybe in the `print` command or the `sprintf()` function) because normally in UTF-8, only the 128 first code points (up to 0x7F) are encoded as a single 8-bit value and the transition from single 8-bit value encoding to multiple 8-bit values encoding happens with the 128th code point (U+0080) for which the UTF-8 encoding is C2 80. As a matter of fact, `printf "\u7F\n" | cat -A` outputs `^?$` and `printf "\u80\n" | cat -A` outputs `M-BM-^@$` as should be.

Answer (score 4):

`^M` is for Control-M (a carriage return), `^H` for Control-H (a backspace). `M-Something` is Meta-Something (Meta- is what the Alt key does in some terminals).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the `M-` notation, but the ones involving `^` uses the [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation):

> Caret notation is a notation for control characters in ASCII.

In particular,

> The digraph stands for the control character whose ASCII code is the
>   same as the character's ASCII code with the uppermost bit, in a 7-bit
>   encoding, reversed.

which you can verify by looking at the ASCII binary (octal) representation:

[image: Source: http://www.asciitable.com]
Image source: http://www.asciitable.com

Because ASCII is such a limited character set (as you can see above), it's straightforward to list all control chars representable by the caret notation, e.g., http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_character_representation.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the definition in the [`key_name(3)` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/key_name)

> Likewise, the `meta`(3X) function allows the caller to change the output of `keyname`, i.e., it determines whether to use the “M-” prefix for “meta” keys (codes in the range 128 to 255). Both `use_legacy_coding`(3X) and `meta`(3X) succeed only after curses is initialized. X/Open Curses does not document the treatment of codes 128 to 159. When treating them as “meta” keys (or if `keyname` is called before initializing curses), this implementation returns strings `“M-^@”`, `“M-^A”`, etc.
>
> [key_name(3X)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/key_name.3x.html)

So basically the <kbd>Meta</kbd> analog of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> version is the **keycode of Ctrl + 128**. You can see that easily in Brian's table. Here's a slightly modified version for ease of comparison

```
$ LC_ALL=C perl -e 'for( my $i=0 ; $i < 128; $i++ ) {
    print ( sprintf( "%c is %d %x\t\t%c is %d %x\n",
        $i, $i, $i, $i + 128, $i + 128, $i + 128 ) );
}' >bytes.txt

$ cat -v bytes.txt
^@ is 0 0       M-^@ is 128 80
^A is 1 1       M-^A is 129 81
^B is 2 2       M-^B is 130 82
^C is 3 3       M-^C is 131 83
...
^Y is 25 19     M-^Y is 153 99
^Z is 26 1a     M-^Z is 154 9a
^[ is 27 1b     M-^[ is 155 9b
^\ is 28 1c     M-^\ is 156 9c
^] is 29 1d     M-^] is 157 9d
^^ is 30 1e     M-^^ is 158 9e
^_ is 31 1f     M-^_ is 159 9f
  is 32 20      M-  is 160 a0
! is 33 21      M-! is 161 a1
" is 34 22      M-" is 162 a2
# is 35 23      M-# is 163 a3
$ is 36 24      M-$ is 164 a4
% is 37 25      M-% is 165 a5
& is 38 26      M-& is 166 a6
' is 39 27      M-' is 167 a7
( is 40 28      M-( is 168 a8
) is 41 29      M-) is 169 a9
* is 42 2a      M-* is 170 aa
+ is 43 2b      M-+ is 171 ab
, is 44 2c      M-, is 172 ac
- is 45 2d      M-- is 173 ad
. is 46 2e      M-. is 174 ae
/ is 47 2f      M-/ is 175 af
0 is 48 30      M-0 is 176 b0
1 is 49 31      M-1 is 177 b1
...
: is 58 3a      M-: is 186 ba
; is 59 3b      M-; is 187 bb
< is 60 3c      M-< is 188 bc
= is 61 3d      M-= is 189 bd
> is 62 3e      M-> is 190 be
? is 63 3f      M-? is 191 bf
@ is 64 40      M-@ is 192 c0
A is 65 41      M-A is 193 c1
B is 66 42      M-B is 194 c2
...
Z is 90 5a      M-Z is 218 da
[ is 91 5b      M-[ is 219 db
\ is 92 5c      M-\ is 220 dc
] is 93 5d      M-] is 221 dd
^ is 94 5e      M-^ is 222 de
_ is 95 5f      M-_ is 223 df
` is 96 60      M-` is 224 e0
a is 97 61      M-a is 225 e1
b is 98 62      M-b is 226 e2
...
z is 122 7a     M-z is 250 fa
{ is 123 7b     M-{ is 251 fb
| is 124 7c     M-| is 252 fc
} is 125 7d     M-} is 253 fd
~ is 126 7e     M-~ is 254 fe
^? is 127 7f        M-^? is 255 ff
```

The part after `M-` on the right is exactly the same as on the left, with the keycodes differ by 128

---

You can also check [cat's source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cat.c#L415), the basic expression is `*bpout++ = ch - 128;` for the Meta key version in the `show_nonprinting` case

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the book.

Unix power tools.
25.7 Show Non-Printing Characters with cat -v or od -c.

"cat -v has its own symbol for characters outside the ASCII range with their high bits set, also called metacharacters. cat -v prints those as M- followed by another character. There are two of them in the cat -v output: M-^? and M-a . To get a metacharacter, you add 200 octal. "Say what?" Let's look at M-a first. The octal value of the letter a is 141. When cat -v prints M-a , it means the character you get by adding 141+200, or 341 octal. You can decode the character cat prints as M-^? in the same way. The ^? stands for the DEL character, which is octal 177. Add 200+177 to get 377 octal. "

Answer (score 0):

### answer by code

coreutils cat src
https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/v9.3/src/cat.c#L415

busybox cat src
https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/1_36_0/libbb/printable.c#L43

```c
        if (ch >= 128) {
            ch -= 128;
            *buf++ = 'M';
            *buf++ = '-';
        }
        if (ch < 32 || ch == 127) {
            *buf++ = '^';
            ch ^= 0x40;
        }
```

- M-ⓒ means  ⓒ +128
- ^ⓒ means  ⓒ -64

  - or ⓒ +64 if ⓒ is `?` // equal to `\x7F`

### try it

```bash
# setup raw input: so that ctrl+c, ctrl+d not terminate cat
$ stty raw

# try input: ctrl+a, ctrl+b.. //but alt+a, alt+b not got M-A, M-B
$ cat | hexdump -ve '1/1 " %02x\r\n"'
^@ 00
^A 01
^B 02
^C 03
^D 04
^E 05
^F 06

# end test, run in another terminal
$ killall hexdump
```