# How to remove degree symbol (M-0 aka superscript zero?) with sed

Tags: linux, sed, special-characters

I have a file that includes temperatures along with a degree symbol that I want to remove. It looks like this in Notepad++:

```
40238230,194°,47136
```

The symbol does not print with a plain `cat`:

```
40238230,194,47136
```

But `cat -e` shows `M-0` where the symbol is:

```
40238230,194M-0,47136
```

How can I get rid of that symbol? I thought the following *sed* would do it (by including only digits and commas), but doesn't:

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9\,]//g'
```

Comment: What `locale` are you using in your terminal?  `echo 40238230,194°,47136| sed 's/°//'
40238230,194,47136`

Comment: My console is UTF-8. The script will end up running on other machines. The answer I flagged should be independent of the locale setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have not setup up your console to use Unicode?

The degree sign is Unicode &#x00B0. In UTF-8 this is \xc2\xb0. So if you console is not using Unicode you will have to replace those two bytes.

The M- notation is described here: [What is the "M- notation" and where is it documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694331/what-is-the-m-notation-and-where-is-it-documented).

```
M-0 is 0xb0
```

On a console with Unicode enabled I get:

```
$ cat foo
122 °C
$ cat -e foo
122 M-BM-0C$
```

Now for removing with sed read: [Remove unicode characters from textfiles - sed , other bash/shell methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562354/remove-unicode-characters-from-textfiles-sed-other-bash-shell-methods)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the unicode characters thread. I tried sed a couple of ways but opted for what seems simplest and broadest (my input is from other sources and could have surprising codes in the future): `iconv -c -t ascii`