# txt file rendered perfectly from pdf, opens with perfect alignment in text editor, can not load into dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, text, geany, non-printing-characters

I can not figure out how generic text processors like Geany or the new default gnome Text Editor parse my text files.  The column alignment is perfect.  Using `cat -nA` sees the correct delimiters, but of course they are mysterious non-printing characters.

The closest I have gotten is `pd.read_fwf`.  I would like to use `pd.read_csv` if I could figure out the right parameter combination.

If anyone has a suggestion about how to tell Pandas to delimit columns on those non-printing characters, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the definitive answer on Stackoverflow.  You have to read the whole discussion.

[Non-printing characters in cat -v](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44952259/1208245)